# Heater causing dry uncomforatable air

Tags: heating, bedroom

My bedroom is a bit cool so I started using an electric space heater (that doesn't have a fan). I noticed it makes the air very dry. What's the best way of counteracting this? I was thinking of putting a bowl of water beside it, using a humidifier or using a fan. Would any of these help?

EDIT: I should ask, are humidifiers safe? I've got wood furniture and a computer in the room and was wondering if they would grow mold or damage electronics? If they are safe to use, should I put it right beside the heater? Should it be a warm mist or cool mist?

UPDATE: it appears the heater blows cold air, and it shouldn't be doing this.

Answer (score 2):

A humidifier is made for this exact purpose.

**However**

I personally do not care for any form of a humidifier, and I tend to like my environment on the drier side (<30% humidity).

Only by using a humidity, and some common sense can you monitor the actual moisture content of the room. Most humidifiers belong to two groups, heat and ultrasonic. The first group simply heats water from a resevoir and allows the steam/vapor to enter the room. The second uses ultrasonic motion to disturb the water from the liquid into the atmosphere, without greatly affecting the temperature.

Most of these are meant to be temporary and mostly intended for those ill with respiratory infections or similar (unless they are part of a central heat/air system).

A better solution would be to identify the reason your room is cold, rather than run a space heater. These are notorious for causing fires, drying out the air, etc.

Any time the humidity starts to creep above 50% and/or a mist/vapor is deposited/concentrated there is a chance for mold/mildew.

Electronics generally do not like any form of moisture, but again, so long as you keep the humidity under 50% and prevent any misting or precipitation, there should not be any issues.

Prior to getting a humidifier or putting out a bowl of water anywhere, I would purchase an inexpensive humidistat to try and figure out what the moisture level is. Watch it for a day or so, then decide how to proceed.

Also, please be safe with your space heater. Many a desk, office and home have been lost to these things.

Comment: Are those safe to use with electronics in the room? Do they cause mold?

Comment: @Celeritas Updated answer for you

Comment: @Celeritas I've checked out some of your other questions and posts about mold, air conditioning, etc. Are you still in the same garage apartment? If so, it seems like you may want to sit down with your landlord and request/suggest some improvements. You definitely appear to have some circulation, heating and cooling issues.

Comment: Nope. New place! Also I was just about to ask a question about a drafty window but noticed there already are some. Hopefully when I fix that I won't need the heater.

Comment: Congratulations on the new place! I find if you have circulating air, even if it's incredibly dry, it's comfortable. The issue is usually when you have warm air (dry or moist) reach cold air that is opposite in moisture content. Make us feel 'weird'

Comment: I got ta humidity meter and it's reading 53%. On the balcony it reads 49%. According the weather network in my area the humidity is 68%. Why all the different numbers? It certainly is conceivable the humidity meter I bought isn't working well.

Comment: Also the humidity meter has a normal, max and min button. What are the differences?

Comment: It is reasonable to have variances even in different rooms of a house of more than 10%. I would read the instructions that came with your humidity meter. Unless we knew the model number, we would just be guessing, and if we knew the model number, we'd look up the instructions. Also - the weather network in your area is probably generalizing the outdoor atmospheric humidity, which will definitely vary from area to area

Comment: Should the outdoor humidity be higher than the indoor humidity?

Comment: This might be more personal preference, but I say yes. I prefer dry as possible, down to about 30%

Comment: I found the instructions

Comment: It still is unclear what the difference is between humidity/max/min. It just says "Press the HUMIDITY/MAX/MIN button once to display the maximum readings. Press the HUMIDITY/MAX/MIN button again to display the minimum readings." If I press the button 3 times I get 49%, 61%, 70% which is a big difference.

Comment: Like a digital thermometer, it could be keeping a history of readings.

Answer (score 1):

Get a meter that measures the relative humidity. Don't just go by what it feels like. If you do add a humidifier, don't go over 50%. Otherwise, things could start to mildew.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for a good humidity meter or are they all pretty much the same?

Comment: I would read reviews on amazon and similar. Buy the best rated one you can deem reasonably priced.